# C#...Help me understand the include of _db.Users.Include("Something")

Tags: c#

A newbie question, I know; however, I see it quite often and don't understand what the .include is doing.

If it matters I'm working in MVC 4 and C#.

I know that _db is a reference to my context. _db.Users references my DbSet Users within the context.

So I have a table with records of users and can do all sorts of things and I'm good there. But what is the .Include("something") doing?

One example I've seen is as follows. I get that it pulls a single user record, of type User, for strUsername. Short of that, I'm lost about the .Include("UserRoles").

```
User user = _db.Users.Include("UserRoles").Single(u => u.username == strUsername);
```

After some help, I understand it is related to eager loading. But I still can't find anything that helps to understand the model structures to accommodate it.

Comment: What did the documentation for that method say when you looked it up?  What did other web pages, articles, blogs, tutorials, etc. say about it when you looked into it after not understanding the documentation, and what aspects of that content did you have trouble understanding, specifically?

Comment: I was considering posting the answer, but I like @Servy's comment better.

Comment: I've tried looking up ".include". I get a lot of junk not even related. I'm having trouble narrowing down the search to even find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Include forces the load of the related data. In your case .Include("UserRoles") means that a User and UserRoles will be loaded in the very same sql query.

Comment: From that, am i correct in understand that it return record(s) from both tables, User and UserRoles, for strUsername.

Comment: Correct. Most probably it will do a tables join in sql query and build both User and UserRoles collection. But depends on your model though. When you call getter User.UserRoles it will return already loaded UserRoles without querying the database. On the other hand, without .Include() in your initial query, if you then call getter User.UserRoles it would cause another database call.

Answer (score 1):

includes is used for eager loading in entity framework

you can find details here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: That helped some, but I'm still missing it.

Answer (score 0):

EF provides possibilities for lazy loading and eager loading, last done by `Include` IQueryable expression.

Consider using following extension method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

It will make your code better maintainable since you forget about magical strings that may result in runtime errors, if you decide to change properties in the model and forget to rename those in `Include` methods.